# How to download a file using puppeteer when href="javascript:void(0);"?

Tags: puppeteer

I have an element-

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0);">click here</a>
```

Clicking on a inside puppeteer opens the link and does not download it.

I have used this code before to download element like this:

```
  await page.evaluate(() => {
                        const pdfLink = document.querySelector(`a`);
                        pdfLink.setAttribute('download', 'File.pdf');
                        pdfLink.click();
                    } );
```

But it is not working here.

Comment: have you tried `page.click('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]')` ?